# Is there any way to prevent different users from delete other user's files in the same share folder (but they can create own new files)?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, permissions, share

On ubuntu I have the following:

```
A folder: `shares`, pemissions 755, owner root:somegroup.
```

Users and groups:

```
user1 user2 (groupx)
user3 user4 (groupy)
user5 (groupz)
```

I need to give the users in `groupx` and `groupy` the permission to create their own data inside share folder, but **every single user can ONLY delete what he created**, nothing more.

`groupz` users can only read content of share without writing.

If that helps, may I get the answer in case of ignoring the groups (just taking care of that each single user can create, and ONLY delete his own created files)?

Can anyone help me how can I get that be giving the right permissions and owners? because nothing help came to my mind.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/why-can-rm-remove-read-only-files) topic this is not possible.

To create/remove files in some dir you need to have a wx permissions to its parent dir. The user can even delete a file that he is not able to read.

The only option I see is to create the subdirectories for each user, where only this user has write permission. (chmod 750)

//Edit:

It's possible!
I was not aware of the [sticky](https://superuser.com/q/350802/661532) bit:

`chmod 1770` on parent dir.

This adds a requirement that only dir owner or file owner can delete a file inside.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I didn't know this functionality too.

Comment: But like this the owner group users cannot delete the file, though they have write permissions, how can I solve that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible in your current design. I would recommend then  creating subdirectories for each grup with 775 permission so users outside the grup can't delete files inside

Comment: Actually it can be done using ACL, I am now sure till now how, but it can surely be done.

Comment: But still your question was about users not groups. :)

Comment: Not completely: `groupz users can only read content of share without writing`, actually I told to ignore groups because I didn't know if it is possible or not, but now I know that it is surely possible